# When I grow up, I want to be (Part 2)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> In my first year of life, everything was too noisy
>   When I turned two, I tried to learn the alphabet, but it felt like I was going in circles
>   After my third birthday, I learned to play tic-tac-toe
>   At age four, everything was about money
>   Year five was about learning to share
>   Once I turned six, I finally started to grow taller

**What happened during my seventh year?**

*Disclaimer: There isn't going to be an exact answer, but I'll accept any answer in a similar narrative style to the story (arbitrary points for creativity) with an explanation of why it fits in*

Comment: This doesnt quite work dependant on where in the world you live. Never the less it is a really good puzzle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my seventh year

> I tried (and failed) at learning to bake pretzels.

Explanation:

> Each year takes place on the shift symbol of a number key on a standard 103-key keyboard, progressing to the right with the passage of time.

So

> **!** indicated all the noise. **@** is a path of concentric loops. **#** is a tic-tac-toe board. **$** is (locally) money. **%** is the piece of a hundred-piece whole, the rest of which went to somebody else. **^** is the direction you advance when getting taller. And **&** looks like a malformed baked good, but no less delicious.

Comment: Don't forget to add an explanation to your answer

Comment: Haha I quite like that one :) but can you explain why?

Comment: I always thought it looked like a dog rubbing his butt on the carpet.. and now you will too  :P

Comment: lol! @TJames I'll never un-see that now :P